# finding the cell that is closest to the current cell with conditions

Tags: excel, cell

I have a row of values - `1,2,3,8,35,7,8,3,5,7,x`

X is where I want the formula to be

I'd like to somehow get the value of the row which 8 is the closest to X (so not row 4 in this case, but row 7)

If I use `match("8",A:A,0)` I get the first match it finds.

How do I find the closest match to the cell where the calculation occurs?

Comment: So, I gather you would like to have last position of "8"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use:

```
{=MATCH(2,1/(A1:A10=8))}
```

just remember it is an array function, so CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER must be used

The answer is based on a trick and behaviour of the MATCH function. I will allow myself to copy the explanation from [ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=72336):

> The magic here is actually in the MATCH function more than the array. Two interesting properties of the match function are being used here:
>
> 1) With MATCH, if no match is found, then the function will return the position of the last value in the array, so if you did =MATCH(8,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}), your result is = 13, since there was no 8 to find in the array
>
> 2) MATCH will return the position of the last value, but won't return the position of an error (or of a blank value), so if you have =MATCH(8,{1,2,3,4,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,7,6,5,4,3,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!}), your result is = 11, as the 3 in the 11th position is the last value in the array
>
> So daddylonglegs' formula checks each cell against the target value with (A1:A13=B1) in the array formula, giving an array with TRUE (or 1) for the positions where the cells match, and with FALSE (or 0) for the rest. Dividing 1 by this results in 1s wherever that array was TRUE, and #DIV/0! wherever that array was false. So his formula is evaluated as
>
> =MATCH(2,{#DIV/0!,1,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,1,#DIV/0!,1,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!,#DIV/0!})
>
> Since no '2' is found in the array, and the last value (1) is found in the 9th position, the MATCH returns 9

Comment: Hey! So long ago that I don't remember it but it was me who posted that original answer at Ozgrid - barry houdini = daddylonglegs!

Comment: Note that it works as described because of the way "binary search" works. LOOKUP uses that and so does MATCH with 3rd argument 1 (or omitted) or VLOOKUP with 4th argument TRUE (or omitted). Binary search gives you a fast lookup because it searches by dividing the search range in two each time, values are expected to be sorted. One side effect of this [utilised here] is that the **last** number is selected when there is no match....because the last number is expected to be the largest

Answer (score 4):

If you want the **last** match you can use this formula in A11

`=MATCH(2,INDEX(1/(A1:A10=8),0))`

[Note: if the values are numeric then 8 is OK - if they are text formatted numbers then you need "8"]

....or do you have values either side of the calculation cell (so nearest might be up or down)?

Comment: what does `MATCH(2,` do ? what does the 2 signify?

Comment: Really nothing, you can put any number there but 1

Comment: Nope - one. Please find the explanation in my answer. It is wizardy, I admit.

Comment: 2 can be replaced by any number > 1 - the formula works on the basis that there will be no number in the result array >= to the lookup value. Note that the added INDEX function is to avoid "array entry"