# Excel: how to use INDIRECT with this kind of formula: {=MATCH(2,1/(A1:A10="something"))}

Tags: arrays, excel, row

I was looking for an answer to a particular problem.  I found a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948030/finding-the-cell-that-is-closest-to-the-current-cell-with-conditions) where the solution is the formula:   {=MATCH(2,1/(A1:A10="something"))}

My question is: how can I use such formula with the **INDIRECT** function?  I need to replace the range A1:A10 with **INDIRECT("A" & ROW()-8 & ":A" & ROW() )** 
 I also made sure I used double quotes for the ="something" part.  I tried for several hours with no success.

Your help will be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use INDIRECT() as it is a volatile function, Use instead INDEX():

```
=MATCH(2,1/(INDEX(A:A,ROW()-8):INDEX(A:A,ROW())=8))
```

This is an array formula that must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter, when exiting edit mode instead of Enter.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula automatically.

Also just to make sure we all understand what this formula is doing.  The Match will return the relative location in that range of nine cells where the last `8` is found.

So if the range had:

```
1
8
2
8
3
8
5
6
7
```

It would return `6`, as that is the last location of `8`.  It will return `6` regardless of the actual row of the match.  The value is relative to the range not the sheet.

Volatile Function recalculate every time Excel Re calculates even if the data to which it refers changes or not.  In contrast non volatile functions only re calculate when the data to which it refers changed, thus keeping the number of calculations to the minimum.

---

Now that you changed your question making my answer wrong.  Here it is with `"something"`

```
=MATCH(2,1/(INDEX(A:A,ROW()-8):INDEX(A:A,ROW())="something"))
```

Comment: Scott:   thank you so much for the fast and great help. Your solution worked perfectly.  Indeed I was trying to return the last "something" in the range.  The final version of the formula I used is:  
=MATCH(2,1/(    A1:INDEX(A:A, ROW() -1  )  ="something"))
I had to change it a little bit 'cause  A1:INDEX(A:A, ROW() )  was giving some circular reference problems.   
Also, thanks for the advice on the volatile function INDIRECT. I noticed some of my excel files were becoming slow 'cause I overuse the INDIRECT function.  I will try to replace those with INDEX.

Comment: @McClausky please mark as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.